# AWS S3: NoSuchBucketException when calling createMultipartUpload

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-s3, multipart-upload

I created the bucket before invoking `S3AsyncClient.createMultipartUpload`, but it still throws `NoSuchBucketException`:

```
private suspend fun initMultipartUpload(): CreateMultipartUploadResponse {

    val ifExists = bucketExists(s3TargetClient, s3Bucket)  // true

    val initRequest = CreateMultipartUploadRequest.builder()
        .bucket(s3Bucket)
        .key(s3Key)
        .build()

    return s3TargetClient.createMultipartUpload(initRequest).await()  // throws NoSuchBucketException: The specified bucket does not exist
}

private fun bucketExists(s3Client: S3AsyncClient, bucketName: String): Boolean {
    runCatching {
        s3Client.headBucket(
            HeadBucketRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .build()
        )
        return true
    }.getOrElse {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: If it says that the bucket doesn't exist, then the bucket doesn't exist. You might be trying in the wrong Region, or the bucket name might have unusual characters in it. Either way, the bucket does not exist in the way that your code is specifying it.

Comment: I'm using the same `s3AsyncClient` so I assume the region should be the same? I also tried "abc" for bucket name, still has same error.

Comment: `abc` should work for a bucket name.  it exists, and for some reason, it's world-writable.